# Is there a way to set RangeAttribute to exclusive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When using the `Range` attribute to check if a number is greater that zero, zero is valid--the range is inclusive. How can I set it to be exclusive? Only numbers greater than zero would be considered valid. I suppose I could do something like the code below but I was hoping there was a better way.

```
[Required]
[Range(0.0000000000001, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Interest must be positive.")]
public double Interest { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can create your own attribute based on range attribute

Comment: e.g. [Custom Reusable Validators](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/09/26/RiaServicesCustomReusableValidators.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid that if possible. It would be simpler if I could just use `Range`. But I guess if it can't be avoided...

Comment: Have you tried Double.MaxValue - 1

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no built-in exclusive `Range` attribute in .NET framework. As *@Vsevolod Goloviznin* pointed out you can create custom attribute. Create a `RangeClusiveAttribute` in order to handle clusive cases. Derive from `ValidationAttribute` base class, then override the `IsValid` method.

```cs
/*

SPDX-License-Identifier:   CC-BY-SA-4.0

SPDX-FileCopyrightText:  © 2022 Siemens Healthcare GmbH

*/

public class RangeClusiveAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public double Minimum { get; set; }

    public bool MinimumExclusive { get; set; }

    public double Maximum { get; set; }

    public bool MaximumExclusive { get; set; }

    public RangeClusiveAttribute()
    {
        Minimum = 0;
        MinimumExclusive = false;
        Maximum = double.MaxValue;
        MaximumExclusive = false;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        double convertedValue;

        try
        {
            convertedValue = Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }
        catch (Exception exception) when (exception is FormatException || exception is InvalidCastException || exception is OverflowException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (MinimumExclusive && MaximumExclusive)
        {
            return Minimum < convertedValue && convertedValue < Maximum;
        }
        else if (!MinimumExclusive && MaximumExclusive)
        {
            return Minimum <= convertedValue && convertedValue < Maximum;
        }
        else if (MinimumExclusive && !MaximumExclusive)
        {
            return Minimum < convertedValue && convertedValue <= Maximum;
        }

        return Minimum <= convertedValue && convertedValue <= Maximum;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        string minimumClusivity = MinimumExclusive ? "exclusively" : "inclusively";
        string maximumClusivity = MaximumExclusive ? "exclusively" : "inclusively";
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, Minimum, minimumClusivity, Maximum, maximumClusivity);
    }
}
```

Minimum and Maximum value and their exclusivity can be specified. By default the minimum value is 0 and the maximum value is the largest possible value of a `double`, comparing inclusively.

Automatically pass if value is null, because `RequiredAttribute` should be used to assert a value is not empty. If the value can not be converted to double then it will be invalid.

There are four comparison cases:

- Both exclusive: **min < value < max**
- Minimum inclusive and maximum exclusive: **min <= value  < max**
- Minimum exclusive and maximum inclusive: **min < value  <= max**
- Both inclusive: **min <= value  <= max**

Attribute can be used as following.

```
[RangeClusive(Minimum = 0, MinimumExclusive = true, Maximum = 3, MaximumExclusive = false,
ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} {2} and {3} {4}")]
public double Interest { get; set; };
```

Example for the formatted error message.

```
DataAnnotation validation failed for members: 'Interest' with the error: 'Value for Interest must be between 0 exclusively and 3 inclusively'.
```

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 8 Preview 2 it is possible to use exclusive or inclusive control in the `Range` attribute.

```cs
[Range(0d, Double.MaxValue, MinimumIsExclusive = true, MaximumIsExclusive = false)]
public double Sample { get; set; }
```

Or even better:

```cs
[Range(0d, Double.PositiveInfinity, MinimumIsExclusive = true, MaximumIsExclusive = false)]
public double Sample { get; set; }
```

It is better to use `Double.PositiveInfinity` because it will give a more readable error message.

For more info: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8-preview-2/#rangeattribute-exclusive-bounds.